# flatten_json is giving me a long list of columns and a single row instead of the required dataframe structure

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, database, csv

I am converting a nested json file having more than 100 records into a flattend csv file. The sample json file is shown below:

```
sampleJson = {
       'record1': 
              {
                'text':[   ['A', 'fried', 'is', 'a', 'nice', 'companion', '.'],  
                           ['The', 'birds', 'are', 'flying', '.']],                           
                'values':[ [0, 1, 0, 0],  
                           [1, 1, 0, 1]],
                'pairs':[  [0, 2],  
                           [2, 1]]
             },
  'record2': 
             {
                'text':[   ['We', 'can', 'work', 'hard', 'together', '.'], 
                           ['Let', 'the', 'things', 'happen', '.'], 
                           ['There', 'is', 'always', 'a', 'way', 'out', '.']],
              'values':[   [0, 1, 0, 0], 
                           [0, 1, 1, 1], 
                           [1, 1, 0, 1]],
               'pairs':[   [0, 2],  
                           [3, 4], 
                           [2, 1]]
             },
     ..... 100 records
       }
```

The csv structure i want from this nested json is:

```
  record1,    A friend is a nice companion.,    0, 1, 0, 0,      [0, 2]
         ,    The bids are flying.,             1, 1, 0, 1,      [2, 1]
  record2,    We can work hard together.,       0, 1, 0, 0,      [0, 2]
         ,    Let the things happen.,           0, 1, 1, 1,      [4, 3]
         ,    There is always a way out.,       1, 1, 0, 1,      [2, 1]
  record3, 
  ....... upto 100 records
```

I used the following code to flatten the nested file:

```
 def flatten_json(y):
   out = {}

   def flatten(x, name=''):
      if type(x) is dict:
        for a in x:
            flatten(x[a], name + a + '_')
      elif type(x) is list:
        i = 0
        for a in x:
            flatten(a, name + str(i) + '_')
            i += 1
      else:
        out[name[:-1]] = x

   flatten(y)
   return out   

flatIt = flatten_json(sampleJson)
df= pd.json_normalize(flatIt) 
df.to_csv('outPutFile.csv', encoding='utf-8')
print(df)
```

I am getting a long list of columns with a structure like record1.text, record1.values, record1.pairs, record2.text and so on with one row and also each word of the sentences in the text is in a separate column.

I will appreciate some help.
Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this example to parse the Json to dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd


sampleJson = {
       'record1': 
              {
                'text':[   ['A', 'fried', 'is', 'a', 'nice', 'companion', '.'],  
                           ['The', 'birds', 'are', 'flying', '.']],                           
                'values':[ [0, 1, 0, 0],  
                           [1, 1, 0, 1]],
                'pairs':[  [0, 2],  
                           [2, 1]]
             },
  'record2': 
             {
                'text':[   ['We', 'can', 'work', 'hard', 'together', '.'], 
                           ['Let', 'the', 'things', 'happen', '.'], 
                           ['There', 'is', 'always', 'a', 'way', 'out', '.']],
               'values':[   [0, 1, 0, 0], 
                           [0, 1, 1, 1], 
                           [1, 1, 0, 1]],
               'pairs':[   [0, 2],  
                           [3, 4], 
                           [2, 1]]
             },
       }

all_data = []
for k, v in sampleJson.items():
    texts, values, pairs = v['text'], v['values'], v['pairs']
    for t, val, p in zip(texts, values, pairs):
        all_data.append({
            'record': k,
            'text': ' '.join(t),
            'pairs': p,
            **{'val_{}'.format(i): val_ for i, val_ in enumerate(val, 1)}
        })

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
print(df)
```

Prints this dataframe:

```
    record                           text   pairs  val_1  val_2  val_3  val_4
0  record1  A fried is a nice companion .  [0, 2]      0      1      0      0
1  record1         The birds are flying .  [2, 1]      1      1      0      1
2  record2    We can work hard together .  [0, 2]      0      1      0      0
3  record2        Let the things happen .  [3, 4]      0      1      1      1
4  record2    There is always a way out .  [2, 1]      1      1      0      1
```

Comment: Hi Andrej, Thanks a lot for the help. I really appreciate it as i was struggling with it for a week. I just have a few questions to understand the code better since it is a chance to learn ( i am extremely lame with nested structures). Why you used zip in second loop ? and if have different numbers instead of text, values and pairs columns. For example, in each record at 2nd level, i have different numbers say 11, 23, 14 in first record and 12, 34 12 in second record and so on with same contents. It will be great if u could guide a bit if u have time otherwise thanks alot.

Comment: @codeDB I used `zip()` to _"tie"_ values from `'text'`, `'values'` and `'pairs'` lists together. Each one item from these lists belong to one row.

Comment: Thanks alot. I managed to solve the second question i asked about having numbers instead of text, values and pairs.